# MediaPlayer not playing sound

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have 2 classes **Stopwatch** and **MyAsyncTaskSW**.

**Stopwatch:**

```
private void Something(){ 
    MediaPlayer countDown = null;
    Ringtone done = null;
    countDown = postaviCountDown(countDown);
    done = postaviFinalSound();
    postaviStopAlarm(stopAlarm, done, counter, startBut);
    MyAsyncTaskSW myAsyncTaskSW = new MyAsyncTaskSW(sec, counter, countDown, done, stopAlarm);
    myAsyncTaskSW.execute(counter);
}

private MediaPlayer postaviCountDown(MediaPlayer mp){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);
    return mp;
}

private Ringtone postaviFinalSound(){
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    return r;
}
```

**MyAsyncTaskSW:**

```
private Integer sekunde;
    private TextView counter;
    private MediaPlayer CountDown;
    private Ringtone Done;
    private Button StopAlarm;

    public MyAsyncTaskSW(Integer Sekunde, TextView Counter, MediaPlayer coundDown, Ringtone done, Button stopAlarm){
        this.sekunde = Sekunde;
        this.counter = Counter;
        this.Done = done;
        this.CountDown = coundDown;
        this.StopAlarm = stopAlarm;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(TextView o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        CountDown.stop();
        Done.play();
        StopAlarm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        counter.setText("Vrijeme isteklo!");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        CountDown.start();
        counter.setText(Integer.toString(values[0]));
    }
```

So **CountDown.start();** is not playing sound at all, while **Done.play();** working just fine.

I even tried to put it like:

```
private void Something(){ 
        MediaPlayer countDown = null;
        Ringtone done = null;
        countDown = postaviCountDown(countDown);
        CountDown.start();
        CountDown.start();
        done = postaviFinalSound();
        postaviStopAlarm(stopAlarm, done, counter, startBut);
        MyAsyncTaskSW myAsyncTaskSW = new MyAsyncTaskSW(sec, counter, countDown, done, stopAlarm);
        myAsyncTaskSW.execute(counter);
    }
```

But still nothing.
I added sound in **res -> raw** folder.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItiyC.png)

Comment: any error you got?

Comment: No, not really (can't see any error in terminal), it is just not playing but application works. Tried on PC an notebook.

Comment: `Done` and `CountDown` are 2 different classes. Why would you expect one work just because the other one works? You need to `prepare()` MediaPlayer before you can `start()` it. Check some MediaPlayer tutorial.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I compare them so community can know that there is nothing wrong with the sound hardware - I know that they are not same class.
I Added CountDown.prepare(); before .start(); on onProgressUpdate but still no sound.